# Set default pattern

Tags: python, design-patterns, default-value

I was wondering if folks might be able to describe their own approaches to how they "set defaults". Say I have a variety of types of objects each of which I'd like to do some initial and regular type of set up with, the sort of thing that'd go wonderfully inside of **init**. Sadly I can't just place this setup in the constructor and I was trying to devise an alternate approach for setting object defaults. What I have so far is as follows:

```
class Defaults():
    """A base class for defaults"""

class UserDefaults(Defaults):  
    timezone = 'CT'

class ProfileDefaults(Defaults):
    active = True



def set_defaults(obj):
    all_default_classes = filter(lambda x: hasattr(x, '__base__') and x.__base__ is Defaults
    default_cls = filter(lambda x: x.startswith(obj.__class__), all_default_classes)[0]
    for el in dir(default_cls):
        if hasattr(obj, el):
            setattr(obj, el, getattr(default_cls, el))
```

Comment: Just so I understand this correctly: This is for some kind of configuration/settings and you want to provide defaults? Why don’t you just use a dictionary for this?

Comment: Why can't you have them in the ctor?

Comment: Im working on a module thats importing data between two systems. This setting of defaults is to satisfy constraints imposed by the system were migrating to. Were hoping to touch those systems as minimally as possible hence not wanting them in the ctor. I suppose a dict would be able accomplish this functionality with a good amount less overhead but that approach feels less structured, at leas the way I'm imagining it.